# Change a columns values if another column's value ends with a specific string

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to find all email domains in column `email` that end with "@gmail.com" or "@googlemail.com" and then change their corresponding `domain` column to Google.

I tried something like this:

```
df.loc[df.email.[-9:] != "gmail.com", "domain"] = "Google"
df.loc[df.email.[-14:] != "googlemail.com", "domain"] = "Google"
```

Which didn't work, so

**Example DF Before**

```
index | email | ... | domain
0 | "example0@gmail.com" | ... | ""
1 | "example1@site.com" | ... | "Site"
2 | "example2@googlemail.com" | ... | ""
3 | "example3@other.org" | ... | ""
```

**Example DF After**

```
index | email | ... | domain
0 | "example0@gmail.com" | ... | "Google"
1 | "example1@site.com" | ... | "Site"
2 | "example2@googlemail.com" | ... | "Google"
3 | "example3@other.org" | ... | ""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html) for boolean mask and set values by condition by `loc` or [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
L = ['gmail.com', 'googlemail.com']
df.loc[df['email'].str.endswith(tuple(L)), 'domain'] = 'Google'
```

Or:

```
df['domain'] = np.where(df['email'].str.endswith(tuple(L)), 'Google', df['domain'])
```

---

```
print (df)
                     email  ...  domain
0       example0@gmail.com  ...  Google
1        example1@site.com  ...    Site
2  example2@googlemail.com  ...  Google
3       example3@other.org  ...     NaN
```

Comment: Thanks, is it possible to also use the inverse? I.e. if not one of domains in L, then change it to "Not Google", but without overwriting anything that is already there?

Comment: @David - sure, only change `df['email'].str.endswith(tuple(L))` to `~df['email'].str.endswith(tuple(L))`